# Jquery $.post question

Tags: java, jquery, spring, post

I have a form with a text field, that I want to submit using post (Jquery).

I am using Java/Spring and Tomcat6 on the server side.

Here comes the problem:

The text is submitted correctly, unless there is a '.' in it.
In that case the text is being truncated (everything after the '.' is ignored.

Example:

1. "Hello, this is a test." -> OK
2. "Hello. This is a test." -> failure

Sentence number 2 will be "Hello" after the post.

this is the code I am using to post:

```
$.post('/Forge/units/'+unitCode+'/addlo/'+learningObjective,$("#searchForm").serialize(),
                    function(data){
                    }
            );
```

I also tried without serializing the form:

> ```
> $.post('/Forge/units/'+unitCode+'/addlo/'+learningObjective,
>                   function(data){
>                   }
>           );
> ```

Does anyone have any idea about what may be causing this problem?

Comment: Please post your code. Try to use firebug and see what is being posted, that way you'd know where's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) for doing AJAX form posting.

Has a lot of useful functions as well as the ajax form posting.